# inflateException error inflating class unknown

Tags: android, android-view, android-titlebar

I am trying to set up a custom title bar and it works when the app starts up. My custom title bar has a button which when clicked takes you to another activity. After the activity it goes to finishes processing it jumps back to my main activity. However when it jumps back I get an error at the point in my code when I try to set a custom title bar why does this happen. I looked at other solution but a lot of them talked about setting the size of the image using 'BitmapFactory' but if that is the case why does it work on start up?

here is my code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        int [] progressVals = getPackets();
        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "HERE 6");

        displayList(progressVals, values);

        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "HERE 7");

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);

        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "HERE 8");

        menuHandler();

        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "HERE 9");

        pendingExerciseHandler();

        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "HERE 10");

    }
```

and here is my logcat

```
12-11 00:51:58.015: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 814 objects / 57696 bytes in 83ms
12-11 00:52:01.184: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 6
12-11 00:52:01.294: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 7
12-11 00:52:01.586: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 572 objects / 29720 bytes in 51ms
12-11 00:52:01.695: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 8
12-11 00:52:01.935: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 9
12-11 00:52:01.975: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 10
12-11 00:52:16.505: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 679 objects / 35472 bytes in 46ms
12-11 00:52:16.784: I/ADD PACKET(307): ON CREATE
12-11 00:52:18.705: W/KeyCharacterMap(307): No keyboard for id 0
12-11 00:52:18.705: W/KeyCharacterMap(307): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-11 00:52:21.645: I/ADD PACKET(307): DISPLAY LIST
12-11 00:52:21.875: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4148 objects / 220688 bytes in 57ms
12-11 00:52:23.025: I/ADD PACKET(307): ITEM CLICKED
12-11 00:52:23.184: I/global(307): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
12-11 00:52:23.545: I/global(307): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
12-11 00:52:24.084: I/global(307): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
12-11 00:52:24.695: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 6
12-11 00:52:24.705: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 7
12-11 00:52:24.985: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3708 objects / 1096704 bytes in 58ms
12-11 00:52:25.085: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 8
12-11 00:52:25.094: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 9
12-11 00:52:25.134: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 10
12-11 00:52:25.635: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1675 objects / 94824 bytes in 54ms
12-11 00:52:26.525: D/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 217 objects / 10608 bytes in 47ms
12-11 00:52:29.035: I/global(307): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
12-11 00:52:32.545: I/RUN ALGO(307): Sports101
12-11 00:52:32.556: I/RUN ALGO(307): Sports101
12-11 00:52:32.556: I/RUN ALGO(307): Sports101
12-11 00:52:34.184: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): ON RESTART
12-11 00:52:34.417: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 6
12-11 00:52:34.435: I/DISPLAY ALL(307): HERE 7
12-11 00:52:34.644: E/dalvikvm-heap(307): 1584884-byte external allocation too large for this process.
12-11 00:52:34.644: E/GraphicsJNI(307): VM won't let us allocate 1584884 bytes
12-11 00:52:34.655: D/AndroidRuntime(307): Shutting down VM
12-11 00:52:34.655: W/dalvikvm(307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dejalearn/com.dejalearn.base.DisplayAllActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onIntChanged(PhoneWindow.java:992)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.updateInt(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setFeatureInt(PhoneWindow.java:933)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.dejalearn.base.DisplayAllActivity.onCreate(DisplayAllActivity.java:53)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  ... 11 more
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  ... 25 more
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
12-11 00:52:34.685: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  ... 29 more
12-11 00:57:34.749: I/Process(307): Sending signal. PID: 307 SIG: 9
12-11 04:52:37.645: D/dalvikvm(8984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 998 objects / 66296 bytes in 77ms
12-11 06:52:28.605: D/dalvikvm(8984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 269 objects / 12336 bytes in 95ms
```

and here is my xml file for the title bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:gravity= "center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#01b8fa">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/title_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/edited_logo_2"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_logo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/notify"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/notify_bubble_blue"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width = "60dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notify_number"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_name_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/title_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="38sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_menu_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/title_menu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I managed to fix this by moving the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` tags above the `android:src` tag in my image button with the id `title_logo`. Once I did that it worked, I'm not sure if it was because of that change or if eclipse was just freaking out earlier.

Comment: ^ actually that didn't work, any suggestions?